# Javascript / jQuery / jqGrid Remove the default text highlight on tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, textarea, highlight

I have an application where I use jqGrid to display some data. When I press tab key in order to jump from a input field to a textarea field, the text that is prefilled in the textarea is highlighted. How can I get rid of the highlight.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$('textarea').on('focus', function(){
    var content = $(this).val();
    alert(content);
});
```

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fg47oyz/1/) tabbing from input to textarea